# import series of csv files as keyframe using handler

Tags: python, animation, scripting, keyframes, csv

I try to import a series of csv files (name_0.csv,name_1.csv,name_2.csv ....) but reading only one file which is the current frame of the scene, if we are at frame 2 thus displaying only the name_2.csv file. My script is working but something is missing at the handler. I put append so it append all the data series but I would like a clean update when new frame.
Thank you

here the code:

```
import bpy, csv, os, sys

path="path...."  
case_name = 'fensap' 

  
def read_frame():
    current_frame=bpy.context.scene.frame_current
    end_frame = 10
    frame_s = bpy.context.scene.render.fps
    with open(os.path.join(path,'{}_{:01d}.csv'.format(case_name,current_frame))) as csvfile:
        content = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', dialect='excel')
        for i,row in enumerate(content):
            if i == 0: continue            # skip header
            x,y,z = row [4], row[5], row[6]#
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius=0.05,location = (float(x), float(y) ,float(z)))
        print("Frame number=",current_frame,"number of particles=",i)

def my_handler(scene):
    read_frame()
    
def register():
     bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler)
     
def unregister():
     bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(my_handler)
      
register()
#unregister()
```

Comment: So you want to track what object is been created by script and *show* them one per frame instead of creating them infinitely? Trying to give the mesh a name that could be determined: `CVS_Mesh_#001` then track them inside an array with unlink, link to scene perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ray thank you for your answer.
I found another way and it works, so ...
Thank you anyway, I put the script in case of someone....

import bpy, csv, os, sys

path="/home/hadrien/Desktop/blender_parti/tuto2/"
case_name = 'fensap'

def read_frame():
for l in bpy.data.objects:
if l.name.startswith("part "):
l.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.delete()

```
current_frame=bpy.context.scene.frame_current
end_frame = 3
if current_frame >= end_frame:
    print("NO EXISTING FRAME")
    return
with open(os.path.join(path,'{}_{:01d}.csv'.format(case_name,current_frame))) as csvfile:
    content = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', dialect='excel')
    for i,row in enumerate(content):
        if i == 0: continue            # skip header
        x,y,z = row [4], row[5], row[6]#
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius=0.05,location = (float(x), float(y) ,float(z)))
        parti = bpy.context.object
        parti.name = 'part ({0:0>2d})'.format(i)
        parti.data.name = 'Mesh ({0:0>2d},)'.format(i)
    print("Frame number=",current_frame,"number of particles=",i)
```

def my_handler(scene):
read_frame()

def register():
print("register")
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler)

def unregister():
print("unregister")
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(my_handler)

register()
#unregister()